# MySQL select datetime where minute matches

Tags: mysql, datetime, select

I have a table which contains a timestamp column. With a given datetime I wish to return all records that matches the given minute regardless if it's before the given second or after.

In other words, I have:

```
2017-04-01 09:41:23
2017-04-02 09:41:02
2017-04-02 09:41:27
2017-04-02 09:42:49
```

Giving:

```
2017-04-02 09:41:30
```

I wish to return:

```
2017-04-02 09:41:02
2017-04-02 09:41:27
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: what you tried so far ?

Comment: SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE updated BETWEEN $time - INTERVAL 1 MINUTE ORDER BY updated DESC

Comment: use DATE_FORMAT and omit the seconds SELECT * FROM myTable where DATE_FORMAT(updated,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%i') =DATE_FORMAT('2017-04-02 09:41:30', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i')

Comment: @JYoThI definitely that works, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just extract down to the minute:

```
select t.*
from t
where date_format(tscol, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i') = date_format('2017-04-02 09:41:30', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i');
```

or, depending on the type of the constant:

```
select t.*
from t
where date_format(tscol, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i') = left('2017-04-02 09:41:30', 16);
```